# Incremental Primary key in mySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, increment

I'm attempting to use a form post to add rows to a mySQL table. Each row has a primary I'm calling quoteID. When a new form is submitted, it should add itself as a row in the table, with a quoteID of one greater than the previous quoteID. It current looks something like this:

```
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login.php");
}
include 'verify.php';
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","$password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("internal", $con);

$previousOrderID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sourcingQuote ORDER BY quoteID DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$newOrderID = $previousOrderID + 1;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

At the moment there are 4 rows in this table, with quoteID's of 1,2,3 and 4. The odd thing is, if I attempt:

```
<? echo $previousOrderID; ?><br>
<? echo $newOrderID; ?><br>
```

The output result is:

```
Resource id #3

4
```

Regardless of how many rows are in the table, $previousOrderID is fixed to 3. How can I correct this? More so, it's correct when I do addition to it, but why does it output 'Resource id #3' in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by choosing the auto increment in phpmyadmin

> [image]

or by sql example the table name is demo and the colon is demo whit the auto increment and its promary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo` (
  `demmo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`demmo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: It is NOT the `AI` he is trying to increment a resource link!

Comment: Very, very helpful. I did this immediately.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is a resource link, you have to get the data:

```
<?php
    $previousOrder = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sourcingQuote` ORDER BY `quoteID` DESC LIMIT 1"); 
    $previousOrder = mysql_fetch_assoc($previousOrder);
    $previousOrderID = $previousOrder['quoteID'];
    $newOrderID = $previousOrderID + 1;

    echo $previousOrderID."<br />";
    echo $newOrderID."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Actually, this is now returning:
1
Array

Comment: Updated code, as I figured out that `quoteID` is your auto increment ID. Tested, works. It worked before too, you just needed to chage drom `ID` to `quoteID`

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do to avoid duplicate is to set the `QuoteID` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed `PRIMARY KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE sourcingQuote
(
    QuoteID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- other columns,
    CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY (QuoteID)
)
```

Comment: It is NOT the `AI` he is trying to increment a resource link!

Answer (score 0):

you can make 'quoteID' as auto increment in mysql phpmyadmin.....

and u gettin the Resource id #3.. beacuse u r priting the resource link.. 
u can print the datas by

```
$previousOrderID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sourcingQuote ORDER BY quoteID DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$previousOrderID = mysql_fetch_assoc($previousOrderID);
$newOrderID = $previousOrderID['ID'] + 1;
```